# Module '"./config"' has no exported member 'app_name'

Tags: typescript, rollup

#### Rediscover

config/index.ts

```
export default {
  app_name: 'app name'
}
```

index.ts

```
import { app_name } from './config/index'
```

error:

```sh
semantic error TS2305 Module '"./config"' has no exported member 'app_name'.
```

#### My question

Current solution:

```
export const app_name = 'app_name'
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

When using export `default`, you can use `import Whatever from "./config";` to import the module - so without the curly braces.

You can only have 1 default export per module, and any other export is a *named* export, importable with the curly braces format.

So, as the TS error states, you indeed have no *named* export called `app_name`

Comment: that, I can't explain :)